# Mass Rename inside Files including sub directories

Tags: linux, centos, rename, bulk

I have many file having "example.com" in them and I want to replace it with "example.co" as i change my site tld, i have rename program installed in my server and have root access too.

Can anybody help me in renaming it.

Sample location of files:

```
/var/html/downloads/folder1/folder1-1/abc(example.com).mp4
/var/html/downloads/folder2/folder2-1/abc(example.com).mp4
/var/html/downloads/folder2/folder2-2/abc(example.com).mp4
/var/html/downloads/folder3/folder3-1/abc(example.com).mp4
```

I hope some1 will help me out here :)

PS: I used this cmd but got below error:

```
cmd: find -name "*example*" | xargs -I '{}' rename s/com/co/ '{}'
```

Error:

```
For more details see rename(1).
rename: not enough arguments

Usage:
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

Comment: rename wants three arguments `from to file`. Try `rename example.com example.co {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to rename but to **substitute** files *in place* so the right tool is [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
find -name '*example*' | xargs -I '{}' sed -i 's/\.com$/.co/' '{}'
```

Comment: Sure, `find` do that by default